# cannot delete firestore reference in batch

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to move firestore user records after authentication using batch. It seems to copy the records but not deleting.

Android app begins in anonymous mode, when user decides to signup, i try to move his records to the new SMS authenticated user. 
Before signup, i get all user records using listRef.get() and a Success listener. I than save the resulted QuerySnapshot. After SMS authentication success, i use the snapshot to copy and delete.

I use the snapshot.getReference() to find the record. I confirmed in debug mode the reference path is correct

To make sure the delete code working, i made a test method and it worked.
The path in firestore is: lists/users/uid/

```
private void retrieveDataBeforeVerify() {
        CollectionReference listRef = db.collection( "lists" ).document("users").
                collection( mCurrentUser.getUid() );

        listRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        mQuerySnapshot = queryDocumentSnapshots; //Save snapshort
                        startPhoneNumberVerification(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString()); //Start auth
                    }
                } );
    }
}
```

After the SMS authentications

```
private void moveDataToNewUser() {

    if (mQuerySnapshot != null) {
        if (mCurrentUser != null) {
            DocumentReference listRef = db.collection( "lists" ).document( "users" );

            WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : mQuerySnapshot) {
                Main main = documentSnapshot.toObject( Main.class );
                batch.set(   listRef.collection( mCurrentUser.getUid() ).document( ) , main); //Copy working correctly
                DocumentReference reference = documentSnapshot.getReference(); //On debug, reference shows correct path
                batch.delete( reference ); //Delete does not work
            }

            batch.commit().addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e( TAG, "moveDataToNewUser: batch failed" );
                }
            } ).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d( TAG, "moveDataToNewUser: batch success" );
                }
            } );

        } 
    }

}
```

**update**

I changed the reference to something non existing and still the onSuccess listener fires. How can it be??

```
DocumentReference reference = documentSnapshot.getReference().collection( "22" ).document("123");
```

**update**

if i comment the first two lines on the for-loop then delete is success. It looks as if the batch cannot process both set and delete on the same batch. I also tried using a transaction but got similar results. does this makes sense?

btw - i am using com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0, i believe it is the latest

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : mQuerySnapshot) {
                    //Main main = documentSnapshot.toObject( Main.class );
                    //batch.set(   listRef.collection( mCurrentUser.getUid() ).document( ) , main); //Copy working correctly
                    DocumentReference reference = documentSnapshot.getReference(); //On debug, reference shows correct path
                    batch.delete( reference ); //Delete success!
                }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what doesn't work?  Are you getting an error, or are you saying that the new document in the batch is created, but the delete doesn't happen?

Comment: No error. batch success and it copy the records to new user correctly but when i check the database, records still their. I am quite sure i am missing something basic but i just spent 3 hours on this :(

Comment: A batch shouldn't complete successfully if any part of the batch fails.  That's the guarantee of a batch (and a transaction).

Comment: I know.. So i guess it is deleting something else... The strange thing is that it worked on a test function. It must be some small mistake..

Comment: I think i now understand the problem. It seems i cannot use both batch.set() and batch.delete() on the same batch. it seems to just ignore the other. If i just delete then its ok. I also tried using transaction and i think the same.. but so, i don't understand how i suppose to move records atomic

Comment: I suggest writing some of the simplest possible code that you can write that does one set and one delete, and see if your observation holds.  The operations shouldn't interfere with each other.  Since we don't have your database and your full logic, it's difficult to reproduce to see what's going on in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190795/discussion-between-ran-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: Hi @epic I am facing a similar problem when I try to `batch.set()` and then `batch.delete()` my old entries.
 If I run those two operations separately then it works fine.  However, if I run them in the same script it neglects the `batch.delete()` operation.
Any chance you managed to resolve this issue? If so, how? Any help would be very appreciated.